# Yii : how to install yii-user

Tags: php, yii

I need to install yii-user.

I am currently referring this page: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/.

But I don't understand some parts, like when they "Change your config main" I don't know which file. As well as "Change your config console:". And I don't know where to run this command `yiic migrate --migrationPath=user.migrations`.

Could anybody help me with detailed installation steps?

Thank you

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: You type all your yiic commands in terminal (for ubuntu) and cmd (for windows)

Comment: @adi I am using fedora

Answer (score 0):

For installing the extension yii-user, download it and copy it under the protected folder.

Steps to follow :

- Generate a new application using the command in your terminal:

***sudo ./yiic webapp /var/www/html/yiisite***

- Download the extension **yii-user** and copy it to **protected** folder of
  the generated site.
- Make the changes in the **yiisite/protected/config/main.php**

Replace **yiisite** with your generated application directory name.

**Some recommendations :** 
Whenever you are about to use a framework or new technology always refer the documentation, it contains a whole lot of information to help you get started. In case you are learning Yii framework, check the documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

For ex : If you are using linux. Go to your yii framework directory and type the following . As I use ubuntu so to create a new application I would type :

**sudo ./yiic webapp /var/www/html/yiisite**

This command would generate a new application for you. And regarding your doubt for the config settings. It will be the file **"Your generated site/protected/config/main.php".**

For Ex : In my case it is **yiisite/protected/config/main.php**

My suggestion would be to spend some time reading the documentation to understand how things work in Yii or watch the video tutorials [Yii Tuts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLj9Qa6ZaZtUC1EQC9HgV15dB4XMcUPlNs)

Hope this helps you.